# How to have several (python) processes watch a folder for items but take action one at a time?

Tags: python

Say I have a python script which watches a folder for new files, and then processes the files (one at a time) based on certain criteria (in their names.)

I need to run several of these "watchers" at the same time, so that they can process several files at once. (Rendering video.)

Once a watcher picks up a file for processing, it renames it (prepending `rendering_`)

What's the best way to make sure that 2 or more of the watchers don't pick up the same file at the same time and try to render the same job?

My only idea is to have each 'watcher' check only when the current time in seconds is x, so that process 1 checks when it's :01 past the minute, etc. But this seems silly, and we'd have to wait a whole minute for every check.

Just to clarify ... say I have 4 instances of `watcher` running. In the watch folder 7 items are added: `job1`..`job7`. I want 1 watcher to pick up 1 job.

When a watcher is done, it should grab the next job. So `watcher1` might do `job1`, `watcher2` does `job2`, etc.

When `watcher1` is done with `job1`, it should pick up `job5`.

I hope that's clear.

Also, I want each 'watcher' running in its own Terminal window, where we can see its progress, as well as easily terminate, or launch more watchers.

Comment: `multiproessing` python module may help:  https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: I looked at that ... but we really want each 'watcher' running in its own Terminal window, where we can see its progress etc.

Comment: Have you considered using an async task queue like celery (or one of it's siblings) ?

Comment: Could you not rename the files as each step is completed? e.g. `job1.step1` is picked up by `watcher1` and as it gets done, rename it to `job1.step2` and gets picked up by `watcher2` and so on?

Comment: @Idlehands the jobs are renamed as soon as picked up (to `rendering_job1`) but I still get collisions occasionally when 2 or more watchers grab a job at the same time.

Comment: No I mean, say you started with a file `job1.file`, have `watcher1` look for `*.file` type, and once `watcher1` is done rendering rename it to `job1.step1`, then `watcher2` *only* watches for `*.step1` files, pick it up, does what it needs and rename it to `*.step2` as `watcher3` *only* watches `*.step3` file... so on so forth until the entire process is done.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using something like multiprocessing I think.

What you can do is have 1 master program that watches for files constantly.

Then when it detects something that master program sends it off to 1 slave and continues watching.

So instead of 5 scripts looking, have 1 looking and the rest processing when the one looking tells them to.

**You asked how I would do this, I'm not experienced and this is probably not a great way to do it:**

In order to do this you can have the main script store the data you want in a variable temporarily. Let's say the variable is called "Data".

Then you can use something like subprocess if in windows to get it running from master script:

```
subprocess.run(["python", "slave_file.py"])
```

Then you can have another python script (the slave scripts) which do:

```
from your_master_script import x
```

and then do things.

Comment: How does one python script tell another to do something?

Comment: @Ze'ev: Do a browser search for "process communication".  There are many on-line documents and tutorials to give you the information you need from here, far better than we can do by guessing your next question, and the one after ...

Answer (score 0):

To expand on my comment, you can try to rename the files and track each file type/name by each watcher like so:

```
watcher 1 -> check for .step0 files
             rename to .step1 when finished
watcher 2 -> check for .step1 files
             rename to .step2 when finished
...
watcher n -> check for .step{n-1} files
             rename to .final_format when finished
```

To demonstrate, here's a sample using `multiprocessing` to instantiate 4 different watchers:

```
import time, glob
from multiprocessing import Process

path = 'Watcher Demo'

class Watcher(object):
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num = num
        self.lifetime = 50.0

    def start(self):
        start = time.time()
        targets = '\\'.join((path, f'*.step{self.num-1}'))
        while time.time() - start <= self.lifetime:
            for filename in glob.glob(targets):
                time.sleep(2) # arificial wait so we can see the effects
                with open(filename, 'a') as file:                    
                    file.write(f"I've been touched inappropriately by watcher {self.num}\n")
                newname = glob.os.path.splitext(filename)[0] + f'.step{self.num}'
                glob.os.rename(filename, newname)

def create_file():
    for i in range(7):
        filename = '\\'.join((path, f'job{i}.step0'))
        with open(filename, 'w') as file:
            file.write(f'new file {i}\n')
        time.sleep(5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if not glob.os.path.exists(path):
        glob.os.mkdir(path)
    watchers = [Watcher(i).start for i in range(1, 5)]
    processes = [Process(target=p) for p in [create_file] + watchers]
    for proc in processes:
        proc.start()
    for proc in processes:
        proc.join()
```

Which will create and process files like so:

```
create_file()          -> *newfile*  -> job0.step0
Watcher(1).start()     -> job0.step0 -> job0.step1
watcher2('job0.step1') -> job0.step1 -> job0.step2
watcher3('job0.step2') -> job0.step2 -> job0.step3
watcher4('job0.step3') -> job0.step3 -> job0.step4
```

And the files (e.g. job0.step4) will be done in order:

> new file 0
>   I've been touched inappropriately by watcher 1
>   I've been touched inappropriately by watcher 2
>   I've been touched inappropriately by watcher 3
>   I've been touched inappropriately by watcher 4

I haven't renamed the file format to a final one as this is just a demo, but it's easily doable as your final code should have different watchers instead of generic ones anyhow.

With `multiprocess` module you won't be able to see separate terminals for each watcher, but this is just to demonstrate the concept... You can always switch to `subprocess` module.

---

As a side note, I do notice a bit of a performance dip while I was testing this.  I'm assuming it's because the program is continuously looping and watching.  A better, more efficient way would be to *schedule your watches as a task* to run in specific time.  You can run watch1 every hour at the dot, watch2 every hour at 15th minute, watch3 ever hour at 30th minute... etc.  This is a way more efficient approach as it only looks for file once, and only process them if found.